# Executing multiple actions simultaneously with result from previous JavaScript action in HTML page

Tags: javascript, html

I am a novice in JS and hence need help. What I am trying to do is when I click on a button on a form it should first execute a action which calls an back end agent to do a data validation from server and the validation result is populated to a field "status". Upto this I have done successfully. Now the button should execute one more action (to get the value from the field "status" and do the next action. Here I am miserably struck. Whats happening is when I am clicking on the action button it is starting executing both the actions at the same time or before the first action could validate and get the results populated onto the "status" field.

I have tried to use timer for the second action, but still its the same result. Please help

Comment: Can you post some example code to get a sense of what you mean by 'status' and 'action'? These terms have overloaded meanings in the context of javascript.

Comment: timers in this situation === bad.  What are you using to post to the server? is it just the form submit or an ajax call?

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, you need to wait for the ajax request return a result. I'm guessing you're using a framework like jQuery for all of this, and if you are, you can specify a callback function, that'll be called when/if the ajax request has successfully completed.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to initiate the second action from the success handler of your ajax validation call.  The ajax call is asychronous so it will happen in the background while your code continues to run.  If you want to wait until it's done before doing the next step, then you need to initiate the second step in the completion handler for the ajax call, not in your main line of code after starting the ajax call.